# Chrome installer error 102

Tags: google-chrome, installation

Whenever I try to install Chrome, I get installer error 102. (It downloads successfully, though.) I'm using [this installer](http://www.google.com/chrome/thankyou.html?brand=GGRY&installdataindex=search-experiment) from [here](http://www.google.com/chrome).

An earlier version of Chrome installed and updated OK a long, long time ago on the same XP computer.

I tried following the instructions [here](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136678), but they didn't seem to help.

Comment: What exaclty happened when you ran the installer from the command-prompt after setting the `tmp` environment-variable?

Comment: @Synetech The exact same thing. It downloads, then gives me error 102 *after* downloading. (AFAIK)

Comment: I've made a post here: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=3ec00cd6a32e7de1&hl=en

Comment: While you wait for find out what’s wrong and fix it, you could try manually unpacking the installer/`.7z`.

Comment: This error may also occur because of insufficient disk space.

Comment: I seriously doubt it. Anyways, it's fixed now, as I said in my answer above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for some odd reason, this worked for me for Chrome 15 Stable.

Put [ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?system=true&standalone=1) inside `C:\chrometemp\`. Then, run `cmd.exe`:

```
cd\
cd chrometemp
set TMP=C:\chrometemp
set WINDIR=C:\WINDOWS
start ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe
```

[See here.](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?fid=3ec00cd6a32e7de10004b0e546dc464e&hl=en)

Comment: cd\ cd chrometemp set TMP=C:\chrometemp set WINDIR=C:\WINDOWS start ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe Still not working, nothing helpful.

Comment: Well there you go. Like I said, you needed to make sure that the `tmp` variable is pointing to an existing folder with sufficient space before running the installer. I guess I didn’t make it clear that you needed to run the installer from the command prompt after doing so (so that the installer inherits the environment variable), but since it was valid, it should not have needed to be (ie, if the variable was correct in the system, then the installer should have worked from anywhere).

Comment: @Synetechinc. I could have sworn I already tried this, but it didn't work in Chrome <15.

Comment: Chances are that when you ran the/an installer, it messed up the environment variables (at least until the next reboot), and so when you ran the installer again, it couldn’t find the temp folder. There’s something weird/bad about Windows in that regard. Whenever a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message is broadcast (as installers are wont to do), environment variables (especially those with other variables in them) suddenly stop resolving until reboot. Whenever this happens to me, I have to open a command prompt and manually set the `tmp` var to run some apps until I can get around to rebooting. `:-|`

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the problem isn’t with Chrome, but with Google Update. Something is blocking Google Update from download and/or installing Chrome (what you download was just a small stub, the actual installer is much larger).

Try installing with the [offline installer](http://www.google.com/support/installer/bin/answer.py?answer=126299&&hl=en) ([alternate](http://www.filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/)) instead.

Comment: I the Google offline Standalone installer, but then I got "Installation failed. Google Chrome installer failed to start.". I tried fixing it using the [best answer's](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=680ef4ac481681d7&hl=en) directions, but the I got Error 102 again. I remember the Softpedia setup worked (for version 10?), but I had to move `chrome.exe` into a different directory, and do other workarounds. But then the built-in updater didn't work.

Comment: Then it definitely sounds like Google Update is getting messed up somehow. Try wiping out Chrome and Update by deleting their folders. (What OS are you running?) For example, delete both `C:\Users\muntoo\AppData\Local\Google\Update` and `C:\Users\muntoo\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application`. (Stop the Google Update service first if it is running: `net stop gupdate`) Then use the offline installer (preferably the one from FileHippo since it directly installs Chrome, whereas the one from Google has a wrapper that first installs Google Update).

Comment: The `gupdate` service doesn't exist on my system. Is there any way to "install"/register it?

Comment: Filehippo's (14.0) installer doesn't even show a window. It starts for a few seconds, then the process terminates. Same with Softpedia's 13 stable.

Comment: Did you try erasing the directories I mentioned above?

Comment: Yeah; I actually moved the entire `Google` directory to the desktop.

Comment: See if you are able to install the [latest version of Chromium](http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/Win/98596/mini_installer.exe). If so, then it’s definitely a Google-related problem (most likely, Google Update-related). If not, then there’s something Chrome/Chromium-related (or maybe something else).

Comment: The Chromium installer starts in Process Explorer, then immediately terminates before the Private/Working memory even exceeds 1MB.

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like something is wrong with your system. Check your `temp` and `tmp` environment variables and make sure that they are valid and pointing to a folder with sufficient space. (Open a command-prompt and type `set tmp` then `dir %tmp%`; repeat for `temp`.)

Comment: [Here are the results.](http://pastebin.com/jAWfMMjE) What do you mean by "sufficient space"?

Comment: Nothing; you’ve got 50GB free on that volume, so it must be something else. What that could be though is a mystery. Are you able to install other software? Have you successfully used any programs since Chrome started acting up?

Comment: Yup; and it started acting up a few months ago. I'm using the PortableApps Chrome right now. I've been able to install/update my various other software since then, so it's exclusively Chrome that has this problem. (For example, I installed Avast on this computer a few weeks ago. And it's not an Antivirus problem either; disabling Avast has no effect. I'm using the standard Windows XP Firewall [bad idea,  but oh well], but I don't think that's a problem, as Chrome downloaded but didn't *install*.)